# MongoDB basic (Relation between two objects)

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongoid

I am totally new in mongoDB.

I have two objects :

```
      public class BusinessUnit{
            [BsonId]
            [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
            public string Address{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
      }

       public class Review
       {
            [BsonId]
            [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public decimal Rating { get; set; } = 0;
            public BusinessUnit BusinessUnit { get; set; }
       }
```

N.B : Please ignore other properties in given images.

I have a business unit and want to save a review document with that business unit.

I save it successfully. But I am facing a problem.

My problem is after saving a BusinessUnit and review (with that business unit) when I update my BusinessUnit's Name it is unchanged in review document.

I want to know why it's happened.
Am I missing something?
Below is my documents.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not work like Relational databases. So if it is updating in one collection, it wont affect other collection data. No idea where ASP.net internally handles the updation process. Otherwise you need to rethink about your design.

Comment: bro, I know that. But how can I solve this problem in asp.net core or am I missing any mongodb concept !